# Camera with speed sensor on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, python, camera, sensor, python-3

im useing raspberry pi 3 with ultrasonic sensor and normal usb camera . so i will connect the raspberry pi to AZURE IOT HUB so ive setted the ultrasonic sensor in a place so if any car pass that place with very shot time so the camera will take picture and send it to Iot hub and than to azure database so . i want to know if this possible if it is . can anyone make code for me please :/ cause i have very short time and im busy on the other side of project and cause im new into this one so its will take time cause i have to search programs etc so i hope i get a nice replay :}

Comment: Hello, sounds like a cool project and welcome to the Raspberry Pi stack exchange. If you haven't already, please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). This question is quite broad an it is not completely clear what your asking. Please add more details and **show that you have done your own research** already.  Thanks!

Comment: @scitronboy the sensor and camera will be connected to the rasberry pi . and if the sensor detect a value so the camera will take picture and send it to iot hub and like that so i need some help in codeing  or how ever cause i need to finish this project in 2 weeks and im still at the beggining

Comment: Ok. Could you [edit you answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/95513/edit) and add some more details, for example what type of sensor and camera you have, and what part you're having trouble with? And while you're waiting for a response, you should go and learn python programming language if you haven't already. Just search google for "python tutorial" and choose one that you like.

Answer (score 2):

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/

This can be good start for you. This example gives the time and distance calculations. You can trigger the Image capture of camera with your specified time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at somethign like Motion  https://motion-project.github.io/  to watch the camera stream and save the image if motion is detected in view of the camera.  Motion can read the pi camera.

Getting the detected speed from a sensor and writing that value onto the image as an overlay would make it look more professional.

Saving images of vehicles that aren't speeding could be useful data too, depending on your requirements.

A quick google returns this    https://gregtinkers.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/car-speed-detector/   as a starting point, but the example images do not capture a licence plate and do not show date/time overlay.

The speed sensor you choose will determine other things, so start there and progress forward.

Comment: the thing is im useing normal usb camera . not the motion detection

Comment: @IkerHameed URL added - the motion software can read the pi camera, and call a script to do the reading of the sensor..   But sounds like your idea is to monitor the sensor for things travelling above a set speed (so not to trip on cats and people) and only take a photo when the detected speed is above some minimum.   Sounds like two different design concepts.